# SQLITE How to Divide two count results in the same query

Tags: sql, sqlite

My current code:

```
SELECT VENDOR.[VENDOR_NAME], DEVICE.[DEVICE_NAME], DEVICE.[PK_DEVICE],MODELDEVICE.[FK_MODELDEVICE_DEVICE],

COUNT(RESULT.[FK_RESULT_COMMAND]) AS TOTAL_TESTS,
COUNT(case when TYPERESULT.[TYPERESULT_NAME]='ERROR' then 1 else null end) as ERROR,
COUNT(case when TYPERESULT.[TYPERESULT_NAME]='OK' then 1 else null end) as OK,
COUNT(case when TYPERESULT.[TYPERESULT_NAME]='SKIP' then 1 else null end) as SKIP,
COUNT(DISTINCT PK_COMMAND) AS COMMAND_COUNT, 
COUNT(DISTINCT RESULT_ORDER) AS RESULT_COUNT
```

The question is that I need another column with the result of dividing total ERROR results in TOTAL_TESTS results, and I don´t know how to do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a preference for using `SUM()` in this case, rather than `COUNT()`.  I think you will see why, because the average is easy to calculate as well:

```
    COUNT(*) AS TOTAL_TESTS,
    SUM(case when TYPERESULT.[TYPERESULT_NAME] = 'ERROR' then 1 else 0 end) as ERROR,
    SUM(case when TYPERESULT.[TYPERESULT_NAME] = 'OK' then 1 else 0 end) as OK,
    AVG(case when TYPERESULT.[TYPERESULT_NAME] = 'ERROR' then 1.0 else 0 end) as ERROR,
    . . .
```

Note the use of `1.0`.  This is because SQLite does integer division, so we need to pass in a non-integer value.

Answer (score 2):

Just divide the 2 columns.

```
SELECT VENDOR.[VENDOR_NAME], DEVICE.[DEVICE_NAME], DEVICE.[PK_DEVICE],MODELDEVICE.[FK_MODELDEVICE_DEVICE],
COUNT(RESULT.[FK_RESULT_COMMAND]) AS TOTAL_TESTS,
COUNT(CASE WHEN TYPERESULT.[TYPERESULT_NAME] = 'ERROR' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS ERROR,
COUNT(CASE WHEN TYPERESULT.[TYPERESULT_NAME] = 'OK' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS OK,
COUNT(CASE WHEN TYPERESULT.[TYPERESULT_NAME] = 'SKIP' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS SKIP,
COUNT(DISTINCT PK_COMMAND) AS COMMAND_COUNT, 
COUNT(DISTINCT RESULT_ORDER) AS RESULT_COUNT,
(COUNT(CASE WHEN TYPERESULT.[TYPERESULT_NAME] = 'ERROR' THEN 1.0 ELSE NULL END))/(COUNT(RESULT.[FK_RESULT_COMMAND])) AS DivColumn
```

Comment: Thanks Matt, but I tried that before and it´s retrieving 0 (zero) all the time in the colum DivColumn. I don´t know why